# How To Use i18n.tr in Ubuntu Touch Projects

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qt, qml, ubuntu-sdk

I have been using **i18n.tr** for a while in my **Ubuntu-Touch** projects. I know what this function is about but I don't know how to add a translation to my project.

Where do I have to place my translation file?
With what name?
How must its content be written?
How should I connect it with my app?
How do I test it with qmlscene ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [TouchWriter](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mitya57/touchwriter/touchwriter/files) code and especially its README, where all needed commands are given.

#### Quick summary

- You need to bind the text domain before using gettext. In C++ you can do it like this:

  ```
  bindtextdomain("domainname", "somedir");
  textdomain("domainname");
  ```

  In Qml you can probably do something like this:

  ```
  i18n.bindtextdomain("domainname", "somedir");
  i18n.domain = "domainname";
  ```

  Be sure to do that *before* `18n.tr` is used.
- To generate `.pot` template and source `.po` files, use these commands:

  ```
  xgettext -C --qt --keyword=tr -p somedir -o messages.pot
  msginit -i somedir/messages.pot -o somedir/somelanguage.po
  ```

  (replace `somedir` with the directory your domain is bound to, and `somelanguage` with the language you want to translate to).
- To generate `.mo` files from source `.po` files, use `msgfmt po-file -o mo-file` command.
- Compiled `.mo` files should be placed inside a directory you bound the text domain to, more specifically in

  ```
  somedir/somelanguage/LC_MESSAGES/domainname.mo
  ```

  (replace `somedir`, `somelanguage` and `domainname` with your values).

Comment: Ok i downloaded the source and checked some of the commands. Do you also know how do I test the translations via qmlscene ?

Comment: @GeorgeSofianos I've updated the answer with instructions of how to bind text domains and where you should place your files. Note that in my case I did that in C++ code, but doing that in QML should work as well.

Comment: (You can easily create .pot and .mo files directly in Qt Creator http://i.imgur.com/I9f1Wg3.png)

Answer (score -1):

The best answer seems to be in the doc. http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.10/qml/mobile/qml-ubuntu-components0-i18n.html

It seems to be a function that translates the word passed to the user's language.

Comment: Please read my question more carefully , especially the part "I know what this function is about" and what I ask after it.